# node package.json scripts having issues on windows

Tags: node.js, package.json

When i ran

**$ npm run kmsEncryptJson $region  $keyArn**

command in windows getting **tools** is not recognized command as internal or external. Although it is working fine on linux.

Package.json Script

"scripts": {
    "kmsEncryptJson": "tools/bin/kms-encrypt-json $jsonfile etc/db.json --outputFile=src/secure/db.json",

Comment: you are pointing to some paths in your package.json (etc/db.json, tools/bin/kms-encrypt-json). Do they exist on windows machine? And did you try to change slashes in those paths.

Comment: These folder locations are exists on windows machine as well. Yes i tried with backslashes also, but this is not working either.

Comment: did you try to specify absolute paths (like C:\...)? Is there some result - error code or message visible in console?